# Imprimir datos obtenidos en listen

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Tengo el siguiente *lib*:

```
module Bitfinex
  module V1::TradesClient

    # Get a list of the most recent trades for the given symbol.
    #
    # @param symbol [IOTUSD] the name of the symbol
    # @param params :timestamp [time] Only show trades at or after this timestamp.
    # @param params :limit_trades [int] Limit the number of trades returned. Must be >= 1.
    # @return [Array]
    # @example:
    #   client.trades
    def trades(symbol="btcusd", params={})
      check_params(params, %i{timestamp limit_trades})
      get("trades/#{symbol}", params).body
    end

    # Listen to the trades using websocket.
    #
    # @param pair [string]
    # @param block [Block] The code to be executed when a new trade is executed
    # @example:
    #   client.listen_trades do |trade|
    #     puts trade.inspect
    #   end
    def listen_trades(pair="BTCUSD", &block)
      raise BlockMissingError unless block_given?
      register_channel pair:pair, channel: 'trades', &block
    end

  end
end
```

Qué debo hacer para:

1. `puts client.listen`
2. Ir sumando los `amount` de `sell` y de `buys`.

gem: https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-rb

doc: https://docs.bitfinex.com/v1/reference#rest-public-trades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy simple si miras el [ejemplo](https://github.com/bitfinexcom/bitfinex-api-rb/blob/master/examples/ticker.rb) en su repositorio así como la [documentación del API](https://bitfinex.readme.io/reference#ws-public-trades).

Este es un ejemplo (básico) para lograr lo que buscas:

```
require 'bitfinex-api-rb'

# Configure the client with the proper KEY/SECRET, you can create a new one from:
# https://www.bitfinex.com/api
Bitfinex::Client.configure do |conf|
  conf.api_key = api_key      # sustituye por tu llave pública
  conf.secret  = api_secret   # sustituye por tu llave privada
  conf.websocket_api_endpoint = "wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws"
end

client = Bitfinex::Client.new
pair   = "BTCUSD"
total  = { buy: 0, sell: 0}

client.listen_trades(pair) do |trade|
  if trade[1] == "tu"
    price  = trade[5]
    amount = trade[6]
    type   = amount >= 0 ? :buy : :sell
    total[type] += amount.abs

    puts "type: #{type}, amount: #{amount.abs}, price: #{price}, total acum: #{total[type]}"
  end
end

client.listen!
```

Fíjate en la documentación que te compartí para que veas exactamente que te devuelve el API y puedas manipular la información más allá de este ejemplo.

Comment: excelente muy bien, no tendras una direccion btc para ayudarte por tus aportes?

Comment: @JeisonPerez Muchas gracias, pero SO es una comunidad de ayuda que no busca lucrar; unas veces ayudo, otras me ayudan (todos ganamos). Si deseas ayuda más personalizada (tipo _mentoring_) puedes encontrarme en [codementor](https://www.codementor.io/gerardogaona).